# Looping and Autoplay not working in swiper in framework7 in VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I am loading images to the swiper dynamically. Problem is loop and autoplay not working. This is framework7 and vuejs project

Code..

```
                <div data-loop="true" data-swiper-autoplay="2000" data-pagination='{"el": ".swiper-pagination"}' data-space-between="20"
                    class="swiper swiper-container swiper-init swiper-container-horizontal">
                    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">                
                        <div class="swiper-slide" v-for="data in filteredAcademyData" :key="data.CARD_ID">
                            <img :src="data.IMAGE_PATH" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```